# Is it possible to show only the prefectures that belongs to the selected country?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I'd like to display **country** and **prefecture** into separated select field.
But prefecture shows them both country name and all the prefectures in table together.

How can I constrain the records of prefecture to the only prefectures that belongs to country, which is selected in previous field selection?

In my models I have models such as

- User (This model has one UserProfile)
- UserProfile (This model belongs to User, and has one Country and one Prefecture)
- Country (This model belongs to UserProfile, and has many Prefectures)
- Prefecture (This model belongs to Country and UserProfile)

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>

  <%= profile_form.label :country_id %><br />
  <%= profile_form.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name_en), :id, :name_en, include_blank: true %>

  <%= profile_form.label :prefecture_id, "State or Province" %><br />
  <%= profile_form.grouped_collection_select :prefecture_id,Country.order(:name_en),:prefectures, :name_en, :id, :name,include_blank: true %>

<% end %>
```

**models/country.rb**

> has_many :prefectures

**models/prefectures.rb**

> belongs_to :country

Comment: You can view prefectures by using country

Answer (score 0):

You have to fire ajax request on change of country,which will fetch prefecture list based on country

You can refer  [blog post](http://paramitech.com/2009/11/dynamically-udating-select-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/) which will help you to how to achieve this.you can refer source code also.